# Connecting to mongos on an Atlas Cluster to see Sharding Status

Tags: mongodb

I just need to perform an sh.status() command to see the sharding status of my mongodb database. 
This command needs to be performed on a mongos, and it is not (yet) clear to me how to perform that. My guess is that I should simply launch a mongo shell from a mongos server directly, but Atlas does not seem to provide direct access to them (I may be wrong).

**EDIT :**

Here is the exception I get when I execute the command from a remote Mongo Shell connected to my cluster :

```
mongoc-shard-00-00-wddpo(mongos-3.6.0)[mongos] mydb> sh.status()
printStackTrace@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:73:15
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@/Users/jondoe/.mongorc.js:98:13
sh.getRecentMigrations@/Users/jondoe/.mongorc.js:1388:28
printShardingStatus@/Users/jondoe/.mongorc.js:1497:30
sh.status@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:89:5
@(shell):1:1

2017-12-12T16:31:59.985+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] uncaught exception:         aggregate failed: {
  "ok": 0,
  "errmsg": "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument",
  "code": 9,
  "codeName": "FailedToParse",
  "$clusterTime": {
    "clusterTime": Timestamp(1513092719, 27),
    "signature": {
      "hash": BinData(0, "Ok0isqe1nHr+D/I9344pcNdxapA="),
      "keyId": NumberLong("6496824061736255491")
    }
  },
  "operationTime": Timestamp(1513092719, 27)
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since I was using Mongo Shell 3.4, I updated to 3.6
After some cleaning (I had to manually delete the home/.mongorc.js prior to installing 3.6 otherwise it had a mess) everything worked as expected

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://mongoc-wddpo.mongodb.net/mydb" --authenticationDatabase admin --username jondoe --password strongestpasswordever
MongoDB shell version v3.6.0
connecting to: mongodb+srv://mongoc-wddpo.mongodb.net/mydb
MongoDB server version: 3.6.0
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5a2953b4841c53c7b10a53f5")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "Mongoc-shard-0",  "host" : "Mongoc-shard-0/mongoc-shard-00-00-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017,mongoc-shard-00-01-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017,mongoc-shard-00-02-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "Mongoc-shard-1",  "host" : "Mongoc-shard-1/mongoc-shard-01-00-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017,mongoc-shard-01-01-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017,mongoc-shard-01-02-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "Mongoc-shard-2",  "host" : "Mongoc-shard-2/mongoc-shard-02-00-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017,mongoc-shard-02-01-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017,mongoc-shard-02-02-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "Mongoc-shard-3",  "host" : "Mongoc-shard-3/mongoc-shard-03-00-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017,mongoc-shard-03-01-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017,mongoc-shard-03-02-wddpo.mongodb.net:27017",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
        "3.6.0" : 12
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
                config.system.sessions
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                Mongoc-shard-0  1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : Mongoc-shard-0 Timestamp(1, 0) 
        {  "_id" : "mydb",  "primary" : "Mongoc-shard-1",  "partitioned" : false }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy a sharded cluster, you connect to mongos and can execute `sh.status()`.

In the cluster overview click "Connect", choose "Connect with the Mongo Shell", and use connection string provided.

**Update**

Just tested it with stock ubuntu client upgraded to v3.6 and new v3.6 cluster.

The client:

```
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.6.0
git version: a57d8e71e6998a2d0afde7edc11bd23e5661c915
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1604
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Connection string copy-pasted from Atlas UI:

```
$ mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster14-74xqx.mongodb.net/test" --authenticationDatabase admin --username user --password password
```

The shell:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.0
connecting to: mongodb+srv://cluster14-74xqx.mongodb.net/test
MongoDB server version: 3.6.0
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5a3106712d26976bf628d75b")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "Cluster14-shard-0",  "host" : "Cluster14-shard-0/cluster14-shard-00-00-74xqx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster14-shard-00-01-74xqx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster14-shard-00-02-74xqx.mongodb.net:27017",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "Cluster14-shard-1",  "host" : "Cluster14-shard-1/cluster14-shard-01-00-74xqx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster14-shard-01-01-74xqx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster14-shard-01-02-74xqx.mongodb.net:27017",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
        "3.6.0" : 6
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. when you say "you connect to mongos" what do you mean exactly ? I understand that I need a direct connection to the terminal on the machines hosting a mongos process (i.e one of the primary shards) and run mongo shell from there. Is that right ? 
Because I am able to connect via a mongo shell installed on my own remote server but sh.status does not work from there (I get an exception, on Mongo 3.6)

Comment: Please see Edit

Comment: There is no any special restrictions. You can login from anywhere as long as the IP of the client is whitelisted on Atlas. I didn't test it with v3.6 tho, working with v3.4.

Comment: The error seems to be related to the changes in aggregation in v3.6 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#aggregate-command-and-results: "If you run the aggregate command, you must include either the cursor option or the explain option."

Comment: @MehdiLAMRANI I have updated the answer with test results. Could you update the question with exact shell version you are using?

Comment: Many Thanks. I had seen the aggregation update factor but had no clue how to deal with.  Updated the Shell, and updated my question (getting a different error now)

Comment: Many Thanks. I had seen the aggregation update factor but had no clue how to deal with.  Updated the Shell, and updated my question (getting a different error now)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161103/discussion-between-mehdi-lamrani-and-alex-blex).